# I want to be able to derive from a class internally, but disallow class in other assemblies to derive from the class

Tags: c#, reflection

Hej

I have the following setup:

Assembly 1

```
public abstract class XX<T> : XX where T: YY { }
public abstract class XX {}
```

Assembly 2

```
public class ZZ : YY {}
public class ZZFriend : XX<ZZ> {}
```

I use this feature in reflection when in YY:

```
public class YY {
  public Type FindFriend {
    return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(
      t => t.BaseType != null &&
      t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
      typeof(XX).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
      t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() == GetType());
  }
}
```

I would like do disallow inheritance of the non generic class XX like:

```
public class ZZFriend: XX {}
```

Alternatively, I need a method like (that can be used in the reflection in YY.FindFrind()):

```
public Type F(Type t) {
  return GetTypeThatIsGeneric(XX, Type genericTypeParameter);
}
```

That can be used in YY as:

```
Typeof(XX<ZZ) == F(typeof(GetType())
```

Hope that makes sense...

Thanks in advance

Søren Rokkedal

Answer (score 6):

You can create an internal constructor in `XX`:

```
public abstract class XX
{
    internal XX()
    {
    }
}
```

(Or if you already have explicitly-declared constructors, make them all private or internal.)

That will prevent any other assemblies from declaring derived classes, because there's be no constructor to chain to.

Comment: +1, but in your trivial case , would I need to call the default constructor?

Comment: @Jodrell: Not sure what you mean - from where? This effectively replaces the public parameterless constructor which would otherwise be generated.

Comment: I can do, `class YY : XX { }` and then `var yy = new YY();`, `yy` is an `XX` and I didn't have to access `XX`'s ctor.

Comment: @Jodrell: You can't declare that class from a different assembly, because it *implicitly* calls `base()`, which is inaccessible.

Comment: Actually, this answers goes to no being able to instantiate from the derived class. I wanted to prevent users from deriving.

Comment: @Rokke: No, you've missed the point. By only having an `internal` constructor, you *can't* derive from this class outside the assembly, as it will not have an accessible constructor to chain to.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to derive from a class internally, but disallow
>   class in other assemblies to derive from the class

Just change the constructor `internal` this will prevent other assemblies from inheriting it and also it prevents construction of it. Nevertheless you can use it outside the assembly.

One disadvantage: You'll need a factory method to create instance of it if you need other assemblies to create instance of your type.